# What are SEP events in this article?

Tags: plasma-physics, cosmic-rays, solar-wind

I am studying [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.09374.pdf); at page 5 it says:

> The occurrence of SEP events with fluences larger than the saturation
>   limit was estimated to be less tha n one per year for the period the
>   LPF spacecraft remained into orbit around L1

but what are *SEP events*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A SEP is a Solar Energetic Particle: basically a cosmic ray, but specifically from the sun. These particles come in bursts, called SEP events.

Some relevant links:

http://lasp.colorado.edu/home/maven/science/instrument-package/sep/

http://lasp.colorado.edu/home/maven/files/2017/01/The-MAVEN-Solar-Energetic-Particle-Investigation.pdf

https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/experimentDisplay.do?id=2013-063A-05